# Afloat 2.4 stopped working on my Mac

Tags: macos

I was using [Afloat 2.4](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/) on my Mac with OS X Lion. Now all of a sudden it stopped working. The Afloat items disappeared from the Window menu, and reinstall does nothing. Anybody here have seen a similar case? How do I get afloat back?

Or are there any other app which allows me to keep certain window on top?

Comment: What happens if you start the application manually? Is there anything of interest in /var/log/... (or Console.app)? Did you do any other installations/updates right before it stopped working?

Comment: @patrix Hmmm... starting it manually makes it work... I cd into the folder and did "open Afloat\ Scripting.app". I don't remember any updates... The only weird thing happened is every time I log on there is an alert saying the startup item SQL is not started for security reasons...